# Why does my SVG button flicker when I press it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG button in my HTML code (I removed all the unnecessary things):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style> #themeButton rect, #themeButton circle { transition: all .3s ease; } </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <svg id="themeButton" width="70" height="30">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" fill="#ddd" rx="15" />
        <circle onclick="toggleTheme()" cx="15" cy="15" r="12" fill="#fff" />
      </svg>
      <script>
        var root = document.documentElement;
        var themeButton = document.getElementById("themeButton");
    
        if (localStorage.getItem("theme")) {
          themeButton.children[0].setAttribute("fill", localStorage.getItem("themeButtonFill"));
          themeButton.children[1].setAttribute("cx", localStorage.getItem("themeButtonX"));
        }
    
        function toggleTheme() {
          if (localStorage.getItem("theme") !== "dark") {
            themeButton.children[0].setAttribute("fill", "#6ee559");
            themeButton.children[1].setAttribute("cx", "55");
            localStorage.setItem("theme", root.id);
            localStorage.setItem("themeButtonFill", "#6ee559");
            localStorage.setItem("themeButtonX", "55");
          } else {
            themeButton.children[0].setAttribute("fill", "#ddd");
            themeButton.children[1].setAttribute("cx", "15");
            localStorage.setItem("theme", root.id);
            localStorage.setItem("themeButtonFill", "#ddd");
            localStorage.setItem("themeButtonX", "15");
          }
        };
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The code does two things:

1. change the position of the circle inside the SVG;
2. change the background of the rectangle inside the SVG.

[image]

What I don’t understand is why that flickering when I press the button happens. It’s like the’re some intermediate “states”, I don’t know.

Comment: Works fine for me too.

Comment: I use Firefox and I still have this bug. I’ll try with different browsers.

Comment: Perhaps using `all` in the transition is causing issues. Have you tried only transitioning the attributes that need transitioning? Have you tried other timing functions?

Comment: I found that, starting with SVG2, `cx` is a Geometry Property, meaning this attribute can also be used as CSS property for circles. Transitioning only it seems to fix the problem at the moment.